# Particle system

Tags: animation, particles

I am working on a particle system and a force field.

When it is time for the particles to move to the force field, they actually do move, but a few of the particles remain behind.

[image]

Why's that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you bake the simulation?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. Also, make sure to take a proper screenshot [HERE](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/)

Comment: I baked it and it gave the same result

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: I have uploaded the file at pasteall.org/blend . The title is motion balls

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OUZq08tFmvpxjrC2Zh5DjgkLlQelKZG_/view?usp=drivesdk  here's the link to the blend file

Comment: Your file is protected, use [Blender Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) or [Pastel](https://pasteall.org/blend/) to upload your file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BNM3akpk" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BNM3akpk/)  here you go

Comment: Sorry for my edits ... Suggestions - Keep only elements that matters (produce the issue) in your blend, in some cases it helps you find issue, it also helps others to understand to your file (we see it for the first time and it is quite hard to know what we are looking at. Same for screens keep them clear as possible (mp3?). And yes, we were asking for more screens of your setup, but particle setup is very long and you have also a lot of other elements ... so generate screens for all of that would be killing. For such thing a blend file is the best. Thank you for your effort and welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

It is (as ussuall) **Cache issue** ... *Delete Bake* never really worked for me. The only way I know to get cache overwriten, is to change Number of particles (+1/-1).

Since you use *Emit from Volume > Grid* you can't change that, but if you change *Distribution* to *Jittered* with particles *Number* like 100 and *Bake* ... all sim is fine (in term - how force are set).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Would try that out now

Comment: Changed the distribution to jittered and set the number of particles to a 100 and baked, still the same.

Comment: Since you can see it is not happening in my file I don't think I can help ... Tested also with collision sphere, because it partially looked like some particles were "catched" by sphere inside due penetration that is happening sometimes for quick movement.